# RequireJS issues accessing app object across app

Tags: requirejs, circular-dependency, shared-objects

I have an application which has an app object which does the start routine and stores useful things like `app.state` and `app.user`. However I am trying to access this app instance **without passing `this` from the app instance all the way around my large codebase**.

Strangely I work on other projects which include app in the same way as in `something.js` and it works but I can't see why.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cannot require app in another file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script data-main="config" src="require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**config.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    deps: ['app']
});
```

**app.js**

```
define([
    'something'
], function(Something) {
    'use strict';

    var App = function() {
        this.name = 'My app';
    };

    return new App();
});
```

**something.js**

```
define([
    'require',
    'app'
], function (require, app) {
    'use strict';

    var SomeModule = function() {
        app = require('app'); // EXCEPTION
        console.log('App:', app);
    };

    return new SomeModule();
});
```

When loading this requirejs exception is throw because of the require in `SomeModule`:

**Uncaught Error: Module name "app" has not been loaded yet for context: _**

Demo of above (see console for error): http://dominictobias.com/circulardep/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you need to have a circular dependency. As stated in the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular) for RequireJS:

> Circular dependencies are rare, and usually a sign that you might want to rethink the design.

This being said, if you do need the circular dependency, the issue with your code is that `require('app')` is called too early. It cannot be called until **after** the module `something` has returned its value. Right now, it is called **before** the value is returned. If you look at the code given as example in the documentation:

```
define(["require", "a"],
    function(require, a) {
        //"a" in this case will be null if a also asked for b,
        //a circular dependency.
        return function(title) {
            return require("a").doSomething();
        }
    }
);
```

you see that the module returns a *function* which then would be called by the code that required the module, which happens after this module has returned its value.

So how do you fix this? What you could do is have the class you return call a function that fetches module `app` whenever needed. So:

```
define([
    'require',
    'app'
], function (require) {
    'use strict';

    var app_;
    function fetch_app() {
        if (app_ === undefined)
            app_ = require("app");
        return app_;
    }

    var SomeModule = function() {
        // ...
    };

    SomeModule.prototype.doSomethingWithApp = function () {
        var app = get_app();
        app.whatever();
    };

    return new SomeModule();
});
```

I've removed `app` from the list of arguments and store the value of the `app` module in `app_` because doing it this way provides for early detection of a missing call to `get_app()` in any method of `SomeModule`. If `app` is made a parameter of the module's factory function then using `app` inside a method without calling `get_app()` first would be detected only if it so happened that no other method that calls `get_app()` was called first. (Of course, I could type `app_` and face the same problem as the one I aim to prevent. It's a matter of respective likelihoods: I'd be very likely to forget to call `get_app()` *everywhere* it is needed because I don't usually write code with circular dependencies. However, I'd be unlikely to type `app_` for `app` because I don't usually put `_` at the end of my variable names.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I was thinking about what you/the docs say about circular dep and I think I have just taken this bad practice from another app without thinking enough about it - you are right I don't need to make this circular loop for the sake of accessing some attached objects I could just require in where needed.

Comment: Yeah, getting rid of the circular dependency will make things much simpler.

Comment: To summarise for readers: you basically can't require in app for `new`'ed dependencies during the initialisation routine